# Variable has type which is not Send

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I'm using the `good_lp` crate to solve an LP problem, then trying to save the solution values to my database using `sea-orm`, which is async.

```
#[debug_handler]
pub async fn compute(
    Extension(database): Extension<DatabaseConnection>,
) -> Html<String> {
    // some computations

    for outcome_name in outcome_names.iter() {
        // set up problem

        let result = p.solve();
        if let Ok(solution) = result {
            for (intervention_name, var) in problem.var_map.iter() {
                let updated_value = solution.value(var.clone()) as i32;
                let updated_size = value_to_size.get(&updated_value).unwrap().to_string();
                update_intervention_outcome(
                    &database,
                    intervention_name.clone(),
                    outcome_name.clone(),
                    updated_size.clone(),
                ).await;
            }
        };
    };
    // return html
}
```

The solution type is not `Send`, but I'm not sure why `solution` getting dropped is a problem or how to fix it.

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/routes/computations.rs:76:1
    |
76  | #[debug_handler]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `compute` is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `impl futures::Future<Output = axum::response::Html<std::string::String>>`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*mut coin_cbc_sys::Cbc_Model`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/routes/computations.rs:341:126
    |
336 |         if let Ok(solution) = result {
    |                   -------- has type `CoinCbcSolution` which is not `Send`
...
341 |                 update_intervention_outcome(
                          &database,
                          intervention_name.clone(),
                          outcome_name.clone(),
                          updated_size.clone(),
                      ).await;
    |                                                                                                                              ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `solution` maybe used later
342 |             }
343 |         };
    |         - `solution` is later dropped here
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't so much that `solution` is dropped, but that it is *used* after the `await`. In this case the compiler pointed out the use caused by dropping the solution at the end of the block, but any kind of use would cause the same problem. In particular accessing `solution` again in the next loop iteration is also not possible.

The problem is that when you `await` inside an async function, that function is paused and it may be resumed from another thread, so any value that's created before the `await` and used after must be able to be sent from the first thread to the second thread. You will need to either make the solution `Send`, or collect everything you need from it and drop it before you `await` anything, e.g.:

```
#[debug_handler]
pub async fn compute(
    Extension(database): Extension<DatabaseConnection>,
) -> Html<String> {
    // some computations

    for outcome_name in outcome_names.iter() {
        // set up problem

        let result = p.solve();
        if let Ok(solution) = result {
            let mut results = vec![];
            for (intervention_name, var) in problem.var_map.iter() {
                let updated_value = solution.value(var.clone()) as i32;
                let updated_size = value_to_size.get(&updated_value).unwrap().to_string();
                results.push ((intervention_name.clone(), updated_size.clone()));
            }
            drop (solution);
            for (intervention_name, updated_size) in results {
                update_intervention_outcome(
                    &database,
                    intervention_name,
                    outcome_name.clone(),
                    updated_size,
                ).await;
            }
        };
    };
    // return html
}
```